# Making enum assignable to type based on said enum

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's my simplified code:

```
enum DetailsDataTypes {
  MACHINE = 'MACHINE',
  USER = 'USER',
  ABSTRACT = 'ABSTRACT',
}

enum PossibleAdditionModes {
  MACHINE = DetailsDataTypes.MACHINE,
  USER = DetailsDataTypes.USER,
  ABSTRACT = DetailsDataTypes.ABSTRACT,
}

enum PossibleEditModes {
  NULL = 'null',
  EDIT = 'edit'
}

enum OptionsEnums {
  MACHINE = PossibleAdditionModes.MACHINE,
  USER = PossibleAdditionModes.USER,
  ABSTRACT = PossibleAdditionModes.ABSTRACT,
  EDIT = PossibleEditModes.EDIT,
  NULL = PossibleEditModes.NULL,
}

type OptionsType = PossibleEditModes | PossibleAdditionModes;
```

Also available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIsAuBDAlgGwM40UgKgTwAdh0oBvAKCigFkBBAYQAkBJAOQFEoBeKAcjqZt2vADSUoAVQDK7AErc+0uaPG0AQlJyyGOBb3Wbt9HCoC+5cqEhQACgHt06ZACNUwWgBMPyeMjshqOw9iMnEBFg4FOCQ0TGxEfCJ0ADpwoTEqJXkeaJQMLFxCYmSsjKgDLR0ohDy4wqTkiqMcMXNLcGh7Rxc3dm94QOCSCipWCQAZcb1wVFQVKnYYZl0eXmB+3nI2q2gAeQJff3R2DuGwhgjOHi6nV3cvHz8AoOK0jjKshRue+-6nweKpVUGkqxi+Dlubk8f38AJSTR0ZUWy3B3TufR8cOSyJa4jGk1RkOAGIGLxS+PGrQs8CKUH2hxA6ESwEJPxJcKgAB9bBCftDHrCyQBuCwAYyO8Cg8AgBAU9Kex1OjRBzRF5GlssQJHlR2ZQqAA)

So the problem is, in a number of places I am trying to assign an enum from `OptionsEnum` to `OptionsType`, but I am getting an error saying that `Argument of type 'StateType.ABSTRACT' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Types'.`.

I am getting a similar error in the playground here:

```
const tmp = OptionsEnums.ABSTRACT;

tmp as OptionsType;
```

But not exactly the same.

Am I missing something? Or am I doing smth completely backwards?

Comment: What's the purpose of `OptionsEnums`? When do you want that rather than the relevant `PossibleEditModes` or `PossibleAdditionModes` ([like this](https://tsplay.dev/mpD2am))?

Comment: It's a part of a bigger React project. `OptionsEnums` is a type for redux reducer. I have a slice, which can be `"machine"`, `"edit"`, `"user"`, `"abstract"`, or `null`.

Comment: `enum` is not really the right tool for the job when you're mixing and matching like this (in fact I'd say that `enum` is almost never the right tool for the job).  You can use `const` objects instead like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3z8jN) and achieve the same effects without the compiler second guessing you.  If that meets your needs I'd be happy to write up an answer; if not, please explain (and preferably demonstrate) why you think your use case needs those `enum` types, and maybe there's a way around it

Comment: That is some confusing code, but please write the answer and I'd appreciate if you could elaborate ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TypeScript `enum`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) are a bit strange in that they don't really align with most of [The TypeScript Design Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals); specifically, they are non-ECMAScript syntax with runtime effects.  They are somewhat of a holdover from a time before such language design goals coalesced.

---

Enums are one of the few places where types are compared [nominally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) as opposed to [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system); it is *supposed* to be an error to compare two different `enum`s even if they have the same value at runtime:

```
enum Foo {
  A = 0
}
enum Bar {
  A = 0
}
const foo: Foo = Bar.A;
// error! Type 'Bar' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
```

So, if you are intentionally mixing and matching different `enum` types, you are likely to run into compiler warnings.

---

Additionally, some of the intended use cases for `enum`s have some possibly surprising or unpleasant effects.  For example, numeric enums can be used for *bit fields*; any `number` is allowed to be assigned to a numeric enum, even if such a number is not one of the enum values; see [microsoft/TypeScript#32690](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32690)).

In your case, you seem to be running into the problem mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#27976](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27976); your `PossibleAdditionModes` and `OptionsEnums` have properties computed from other enums.  This (silently) prevents them from being a "literal enum" in which the enum type is considered to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  Instead it is widened to just a numeric enum where the compiler no longer "sees" the individual literal types that make up the enum.  This behavior is apparently intentional, but not anything you want.

So any member of, say, `OptionsEnums`, will only be seen as being of type `OptionsEnum`:

```
const hmm = OptionsEnums.ABSTRACT; // const hmm: OptionsEnums
```

And so the assignment to `OptionsType` fails:

```
const tmp: OptionsType = hmm; // error!
```

Here you want the compiler to keep track of the literal type of `OptionsEnums.ABSTRACT` and let you use it in a place that accepts an `OptionsType`.  But `enum`s don't make this easy for you.

---

As the language has progressed, there have been changes that are a better fit for some use cases than `enum`s are.  This doesn't necessarily mean that nobody should ever use `enum`s, but if you find yourself struggling with them, it might be a good idea to step back and figure out if `enum`s are really the right tool for the job.

One approach is to [replace `enum`s with plain objects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums).  At runtime, your `enum`s are just an object with keys and values.  And at compile time, you're using the enum type name to mean a union of its values, and you want the compiler to keep track of the literal types of these values.  So if you make a plain object, and use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to keep track of the literal types of its values, and make a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) for the union-of-these-values, you can get `enum`-like behavior without all of the peculiarities of `enum`.  For example:

```
enum Foo {
  A = 0,
  B = 1
}
```

becomes

```
const Foo = {
  A: 0,
  B: 1
} as const;

type Foo = (typeof Foo)[keyof typeof Foo];
```

The type of `Foo` the value is

```
/* const Foo: {
    readonly A: 0;
    readonly B: 1;
} */
```

and the type named `Foo` is

```
// type Foo = 0 | 1
```

And suddenly the failing code from before will work:

```
const foo: Foo = Bar.A; // okay
```

---

So let's replace your `enum`s with this:

```
const DetailsDataTypes = {
  MACHINE: 'MACHINE',
  USER: 'USER',
  ABSTRACT: 'ABSTRACT',
} as const
type DetailsDataTypes = (typeof DetailsDataTypes)[keyof typeof DetailsDataTypes];

const PossibleAdditionModes = {
  MACHINE: DetailsDataTypes.MACHINE,
  USER: DetailsDataTypes.USER,
  ABSTRACT: DetailsDataTypes.ABSTRACT,
} as const
type PossibleAdditionModes = (typeof PossibleAdditionModes)[keyof typeof PossibleAdditionModes]

const PossibleEditModes = {
  NULL: 'null',
  EDIT: 'edit'
} as const;
type PossibleEditModes = (typeof PossibleEditModes)[keyof typeof PossibleEditModes]

const OptionsEnums = {
  MACHINE: PossibleAdditionModes.MACHINE,
  USER: PossibleAdditionModes.USER,
  ABSTRACT: PossibleAdditionModes.ABSTRACT,
  EDIT: PossibleEditModes.EDIT,
  NULL: PossibleEditModes.NULL,
} as const;
type OptionsEnums = (typeof OptionsEnums)[keyof typeof OptionsEnums]
```

If you inspect some types, you'll see literals:

```
// type PossibleEditModes = "null" | "edit"
// type OptionsEnums = "null" | "edit" | "MACHINE" | "USER" | "ABSTRACT"
```

And so your assignment will just work:

```
type OptionsType = PossibleEditModes | PossibleAdditionModes;
const hmm = OptionsEnums.ABSTRACT; // "ABSTRACT"
const tmp: OptionsType = hmm; // okay
```

The compiler sees that `hmm` is of type `"ABSTRACT"`, which is allowed to be assigned to `OptionsType`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgkkJgBXMJAEQgBcQMAbKSkOgFQE8Zo9CikAsgEEAwgAkAkgDkAokgC8SAOTDx0mUoA0fIgFUAyjIBKC5QeNadSIQCF9bI6Lamlt+45FtLRAL74+JORIAAoA9lBQGABGDBBCACbxGDQYocACofE8BPyCopKyptR0jMysIJzcUAB0qgUy2rnmJorF9Ews7FzQ1c2N-G4OTkW07WVdVdWDHmz9fv5EgRRhEdGxMkk0GVlQvLlSugAyhy5kDAze-DKUEs6KShCbSnzzi2QUKDApaVAy77s5fh1dSmFaRGJxRLJVLpTI9YGyfp6QwtELhcGxBKbGHbHp9KzTYaKMFrSHYtK4mqEzxIpDXW6g9GkjbJSnVemzKwHY6M1YQllbOE1bmHOYLJA0bqoL4wqCVZDEpn8zaUpAAHzRfMxUO+sJ2AG5xfAfjQkAALMAURSfXW-f5TOxDTz6pAAeldSGNwCgpotYAAXNLbX9yFAjSaJWAYIGbbL5aY-S73cQ0GhQmgAITipZIABioVCewGpgADLSbKYAIwvALvJA2EBoItEISlmtEL0+pAAMwLgfzhcUDbQU0NRGTEFT6YzSHjSmHSiQGF2wFCppAqywoAhEsLku4ygHSmq-nw838ndNbVKnQq3V2ikBCJkgZU+XUl2ar+al2pbFff6WD4SAbp6Jr4PuyDXh05Tyg+SAABSQaE3ZUKMN6wfeACUADaADWEAcChErdMR0HjHeVQALqGvgl6ahiZLQhSQqmE+76yIG5G3nBtQcQ0fBfmhJQwRMeIov0f5cehomUT0f7aMBoGXhBUokhCWLMXqPCKEhpGoep2rktpUC4QRRGochBlKkZWmUlRF4RoZEACqqj58CKr5nBc-Qcq+jzJM8Sm7JehqQQxzIqqxulWRFyqskKZmEcRsXOa5QoOcm4VpVFOymAARN5+Xqkg+UBTQ+WOd6pqxj8IZgPB7FqJxcW2bqbLPv0QnOZp7VCr0El8FJrVMX1OwOu4Ti+Tc-4jel40cv0nlzblPQiopIEhSaYVSrV3r1fBencMRe12qGSUWSRx2oadB00fgWW7TKdX-AVRUlWVmzFRq+XPt9pXNP9+V-pVqkHqd8aKlqLmrbsGo9TqOJCrR9F+qYt32n+SYesDjozJV9E0FGMbPd6kPmpa2NIKEeEgBwp70QObFDYGZZ8DYgbVsFYHVYaroAFQ812A6BoCRBoBAIDxGkDAcNYrNjvwEtSzLcsc0glaGsB-Ouv44VMzF+l5gWF0pUbA6ZR6+sFqWJXVnREbDszLas2em1CzQKMRr2oT9jbQ6NqOboejTdP+EAA)

Comment: That makes sense. So I also needed to cast it to the right enum, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cast it to the right enum"; I didn't do any casting in my answer (unless you count a `const` assertion, which I wouldn't) so I'm not sure what you're referring to.